# Jumplists broken except visual studio

Tags: windows-10, jumplist, windows-10-v1903

Every app's jumplists are broken (both recent and actions) except for VS 2017 & VS 2015. Both MS apps (VS code/edge/office/etc) & non-MS apps are broken. This started happening recently after windows update.

I'm on win10 v1903 build 18362.295. Any tips? Thanks in advance

Edit: Distributed COM errors in event viewer look like this:

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
 and APPID 
{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}
 to the user office\ryan SID (S-1-5-21-1353398642-1024311328-3791363499-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.18362.267_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy SID (S-1-15-2-155514346-2573954481-755741238-1654018636-1233331829-3075935687-2861478708). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

Comment: What does it mean "broken"? What happens?

Comment: Clicking either recent or actions results in nothing happening and the jumplist closing

Answer (score 1):

Broken jumplists after a Windows Update, or with no reason, has always been a problem
in Windows. Below are solutions that worked for some people.

1. Run [sfc /scannow and Dism](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
2. Click repeatedly some jump list that does not work, then look in the
   Event Viewer for error messages, and especially in the section
   `Windows Logs -> System`. Let me know if you find anything.
3. Turn jumplists off and on, as described in
   [How to Turn On or Off 'Recent Items' and 'Frequent Places' in Jump Lists in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3469-turn-off-recent-items-frequent-places-windows-10-a.html).
   If it works jumplists will start again as empty, but check if the following
   folders are empty (clear them if not, navigating to them by entering in Explorer):

   ```
   %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
   %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations
   ```
4. Check the registry using `regedit` under key
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`,
   for valid jumplist lengths
   for "Pinned" items and "Recent" items and reboot if you change any:

   - Value `JumpListItems_Maximum` of type DWORD (32 bit).
   - Value `Start_JumpListItems` of type DWORD (32 bit).
5. Create a new user account and see if jumplists work in it.
   If they do, your account profile is corrupted and has better be discarded.
6. Boot Windows in Safe mode and check if jumplists now work.
   If they do, then some installed product is causing the problem, so test by
   disabling startup items. Begin with disabling all security products and then
   the others. The tool to use for non-security software would be
   [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).
   Reboot to test.
7. [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
   which is the same as doing a major Windows update.

Comment: I tried most of what you suggested without success (I didn't do 7). I do get a bunch of DCOM errors in my event log when I try to use jumplist items. Updated post with errors

Comment: These DCOM errors are not a problem and can be ignored. See [Why Certain DCOM 10016 Events Don't Matter](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/110023-why-certain-dcom-10016-events-dont-matter.html). Attempting to silence them may cause more serious problems.